# A graphics card and driver with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher is required error

Tags: error, opengl, hardware

I can't execute newest Blender 2.80, it says that I need a graphics card that supports OpenGL 3.3 or higher

`ERROR: A graphics card and driver with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher is required`

- Processor: AMD A6-3670 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics, 2695MHz
- BIOS Version: HPQOEM - 1072009
- Dedicated GPU: [AMD Radeon HD 6530D Graphics](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/radeon-hd-6530d-igp.c835)

This is a very old PC, but when I search online it seems that theoretically Blender 2.8 should run since my openGL is 4.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately your graphics card doesn't fulfill the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) of Blender 2.8. The Radeon HD 6530D has the old Terascale 2 architecture and GCN first generation or newer is required. You won't be able to run Blender 2.8 on your hardware.

Comment: If I buy a GT 1030 will I be able to run it?

Comment: @Toriality yes with the Nvidia Geforce 1030 GT you will be able to run Blender, however from the specification that I found GPU rendering will not be possible with it, you'll have to render on the CPU.

Comment: I use two 2080TIs and I get this error all of the time. Blender V2.8+ is simply bugged, sometimes it works fine, and other times it won't even start. V2.79 never had nearly so many flaws..

Comment: @Logic1 Sounds more like an issue with your OS or drivers to me. Make sure that you're using one of your 2080 TI to start Blender and not the integrated graphics from your CPU. Update your graphics driver directly from the Nvidia website or GeForce Experience.

Comment: @Robert Gützkow - nah, I tried all of that and it does the same on Win8 too.. It's a bug in Blender that causes it. The devs have not fully tested it so they do not uncover the bugs that power users get to see. I have a quad-head display, and some blender files try to open windows off screen (if they were saved that way) this causes Blender to crash violently without recovery options, hell, if I tryed the share that file then it would be corrupted for anyone else without the same display configureation. Not very well designed IMHO, blender 2.8+ is so flawed...

Comment: @Logic1 For the problematic file you've mentioned, try to  uncheck *Load UI* when opening the file through *File > Open*. [They can't fix bugs that aren't reported.](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/). Create a bug report either through that link or *Help > Report a Bug*. Attach your system information, the driver versions, display configuration and affected blend file to the report.

Comment: I will keep "Load UI" in mind, Thank you for that hint!!

Comment: @Logic1 I cant reply to you directly but thank you so much for the Uncheck load UI" suggestion. I have been trying to work this out for weeks and the error has been leaving me locked out of my projects and wasted so many hours. To add a bit more clarification for other people who have the same issue:
after loading blender, go to file, open. then in the top right click the cog icon. then uncheck *Load UI*. after that load the project that was causing the error. this instantly fixed the issue for me. If you see this, would you mind explaining to me how you worked this out and why the error occur

Comment: @PeskyNgon Disabling *Load UI* results in using the default UI layout, ignoring the one saved in the project file. Since the issue was caused by a window positioned of screen (for the issue described by Logic1), this was the most obvious workaround.

Comment: @PeskyNgon oh, haha, no, that credit actually belongs to Robert Gützkow, he's the one who clarified the issue. Blender was crashing if multiple displays were used and save Blender file with a detached window somewhere. His solution works 100%. But I'm glad our conversation helped out!

Comment: Using Blender 2.93 now and this error is appearing whenever I click "save" from the file menu. Even a completely new/blank project clicking "save" or "save as" results in this error and a crash - However I think this is still related to multi-gpu bugs in Blender. To resolve this I must open Blender by right clicking and selecting "Render OpenGL on" then select one of my GPUs. "They can't fix bugs that aren't reported" suggests they don't test the software.

Answer (score 1):

For others that might come to this who do have a graphics card that they think is supported. Try just updating your drivers and OS updates and restart. It worked for me on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing pop up

I ended up needing to update the driver

I downloaded the `Intel® Driver & Support Assistant` and let it do a system check
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html

I also found the latest driver for my intel computer in the link below
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/98909/graphics/intel-hd-graphics-family/intel-hd-graphics-630.html

Answer (score 0):

For me, plugging the two monitors on the same graphic card (have two) fixed the problem.